# Renderizar un componente dos veces alterando el estado del reducer (REDUX)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux

Estoy realizando un proyecto en MERN para un curso. Se muestra una lista de paises y al hacer click en cualquiera se abre una nueva pagina mostrando itinerarios con distintas actividades con el siquiente componente:

```
class CityItinerary extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount(){
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    await this.props.getItineraries(params.cityID);
  }
  render(){
    const {itineraries} = this.props.itinerary;
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <h4>Available MyTineraries:</h4>
        <div id="itcontainer">
          {itineraries.map((itinerary, index) =>
            <div id="itinerary">
              <div id="divImg">
                <img src={itinerary.profilePic} id="profilePic"></img>
              </div>
              <div id="itineraryInfo">
                <h4>{itinerary.title}</h4>
                <div id="feedback">
                  <p>Likes: {itinerary.rating}</p>
                  <p>{itinerary.duration} hours</p>
                  <p>${itinerary.price}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>{itinerary.hashtag}</p>
              <div>
                <Activity id={itinerary._id}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  itinerary: state.itinerary,
  city: state.city
});

export default connect (mapStateToProps,{getItineraries})(CityItinerary);
```

Al llamar al componente `Activity` que es el que vendría a cargar las actividades debajo de cada itinerario lo que sucede es que me renderiza solamente las actividades del ultimo itinerario cada vez que llamo al componente quedándome todas iguales.

```
class Activity extends React.Component {

    async componentDidMount(){
        await this.props.getActivities(this.props.id)
    }

    render(){
        const {activities} = this.props.activity;
        return (
            <div>
                {activities.map(activity =>
                    <p>{activity.title}</p>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    activity: state.activity
});


export default connect (mapStateToProps,{getActivities})(Activity);
```

Imagenes para mostrar a lo que me refiero:

[image: Primera vez que se llama a las actividades, se cargan en el estado correspondientemente segun el itinerario]

[image: Se llama a actividades por segunda vez, secargan las actividades correspondientes pero la paginas renderiza solamente esta en ambos itinerarios]

Dejo tambien los reducers y actions para brindar mas informacion:

ActivitiesActions

```
export const getActivities = (id) => async dispatch => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/activities/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(datos => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_ACTIVITIES,
          payload: datos
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

activitiesReducer:

```
const initialState = {
  activities: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_ACTIVITIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        activities: action.payload
      }
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu problema lo tienes en tu reducer `activitiesReducer`:

```
case GET_ACTIVITIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        activities: action.payload // siempre estas sobreescribiendo activities
      }
```

Siempre estas asignando el valor de payload a activities, en lugar de concatenar lo que ya tienes en ese arreglo con lo nuevo que te llega en el payload.

Algo que podrias hacer seria algo asi:

```
case GET_ACTIVITIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        activities: [...state.activities, action.payload] 
      }
```

En este caso estas creando un nuevo arreglo de lo que ya estaba en state.activities a activities con lo nuevo que te llega en el payload.

Comment: El problema que yo tengo es que `Activities` en este caso es llamado dos veces en `CityItinerary` verdad? lo que yo busco es que cuando se llama la primera vez, llene el state de actividades con lo que obtiene de la llamada al api, y lo mapee en el primer itinerary("Gaudi in a day").  Luego cuando sea llamado la segunda vez, que vuelva a pedir los datos correspondientes a la api y con estos nuevos datos llene el segundo itinerary("Tappa till you droppa"). Pero por algun motivo, en ambos itinerary me mapea solamente lo de la segunda llamada. Tanto asi como con la correccion que me has hecho.